# Can not move to other buffers unless I save the current one

Tags: buffers

I launch vim with two files. I can move from one file to the other by `:bp` or `:bn` quite happily. But as soon as I make a change to `file1` it won't allow me to move to the other buffer unless I save the changes! I should be able to move between buffers and edit them without having to save (unless I want to close the buffer).

I get the message:

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

this is the version I am using (with Ubuntu 20.04):

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 20 2021 11:42:42)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `set hidden` to your vimrc.

Although `:h 'hidden'` doesn't state it clearly, it would allow you to switch buffers without saving them.

Comment: Thanks Maxim it worked. In my previous laptop/installation I didn't have this problem. I wonder if set hidden was in the .vimrc by default and has now been removed.